# MySQL query to copy date from different columns

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I have the following 6 integer db columns:

- Year
- Day
- Month
- Hour
- Minute
- Second

I need a query that takes these values for every row, combines them into a DATETIME and puts into another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the most efficient but you could do this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_date = CONCAT(my_year, '-', my_month, '-', my_day, ' ',
    my_hour, ':', my_mins, ':', my_seconds)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I needed to use double quotes (") instead of apostrophes ('), but this worked

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all into a string and then convert that string to `datetime`, like so:

```
update tbl
set datecol = cast(cast(`year` as varchar) + '-' +
              cast(`month` as varchar) + '-' + 
              cast(`day` as varchar) + ' ' +
              cast(`hour` as varchar) + ':' +
              cast(`minute` as varchar) + ':' +
              cast(`second` as varchar) as datetime)
```

Although, I think MySQL uses `concat`, so it would be:

```
cast(concat(cast(`year` as varchar), '-', cast(`month` as varchar), '-',...) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) your data together to make something that looks like a DATETIME value

```
CONCAT(year,'-', month, '-', day,' ',hour, ':', min, ':', sec)
```

While you could use that directly, you could also turn into a real DATETIME by using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with it, e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE(
   CONCAT(year,'-', month, '-', day,' ',hour, ':', min, ':', sec),
   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `y` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s` int(4) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO x SELECT 2009, 9, 1, 9, 59, 59;
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(y,'-', m,'-', d,'-', h,'-', i,'-', s), '%Y-%m-%d-%h-%i-%s') FROM x;
```